# Can you send a SENTRI by mail to another country?

Tags: usa, mexico, sentri

I live in the US, a relative lives in Mexico. When my relative applied for his SENTRI (Secure Electronic Network for Travelers Rapid Inspection) the online form only allowed US addresses so he used mine. They sent me his SENTRI and I'm trying to give it to him. Is it legal to send it over mail/fedex/ups?

I couldn't find information online about it. Sending sensitive documents by mail is always delicate and the current immigration tension between the two countries make me hesitate.

Comment: I don't think it's illegal. It might be a problem if you can't trust the postal service. Can you deliver it by hand?

Comment: It would be complicated. I don't live near a border and flying is time consuming and expensive.

Comment: If he plans to visit you soon, then you can always give it to him then. Otherwise you're probably best off to send it via UPS/DHL/whoever.

Comment: He does not plan to visit any time soon. I live way to far for him to visit me often. Is prohibitively expensive. I guess I'll go through the fedex route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason why you can't mail or courier the SENTRI card to him.  It's important that the US Department of Homeland Security, which issued the card, is aware that he lives in Mexico, but if they're not willing to ship the card there, but will give the card to residents of Mexico, I don't see any legal impediment in forwarding the card.

You may want to send the card with a tracked service, although, interestingly, the U.S. uses ordinary untracked first class mail to mail trusted traveler cards to Canada (from personal experience with NEXUS).

Comment: For the record. I sent the card through a tracked service and had no problems. In case customs opened the package and found it strange for someone to mail that kind of documents I left a note along with the documents saying who I am, how to contact me and explaining why I was mailing such document.

I'll never be sure if they actually read the note or not. But the document made it to the destination without delays.